# How to show foreign key values in SQL instead of its ID-s

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I encountered a problem while making a calendar. I have a table named `REZERVACIJE` (reservations) with columns like `name`, `start date`, `end date`, etc.; and also a `reservation_type_FK`, a foreign key that connects it to another table where reservation types are written down with columns like name, price, etc.

Now my question is:

How do I show the name of the reservation types instead of the ID-s?
my current SQL query is like this:

```sql
select 
    ID_REZ, /*ID of the reservation, number goes up by 1 on every insert automatically generated*/
    START_REZ, /*DATE OF THE START OF THE RESERVATION*/
    END_REZ, /*DATE OF THE END OF THE RESERVATION*/
    DETAILS_REZ, /*VARCHAR2 - comments on the reservation*/
    case 
        when DETAILS_REZ is not null 
        then title || '[' || QUANTITY_REZ || 'x ' || /*HERE I WANT TO DISPLAY THE FK NAME*/ 
             || ' hours on ' || NUMBER_OF_HOURS || ' - ' || DETAILS_REZ || ' ]'
    end as title,
    QUANTITY_REZ, /* NUMBER Quantity of things on the reservation */
    NUMBER_OF_HOURS, /*NUMBER of hours of the reservation calculated automatically*/
    case
        when REZ_TYPE_FK = 8
        then  'apex-cal-red' /*THIS FK is a number 
Identity: always, in increments of 1 that connects to another table that has a name price etc and is saved in my RESERVATION table as a foreign key and I don't want to display it as a number but as a name of the RESERVATION TYPE*/
        when REZ_TYPE_FK = 9 then  'apex-cal-orange'
        when REZ_TYPE_FK = 10  then  'apex-cal-blue'
        when REZ_TYPE_FK = 11 then 'apex-cal-green'
        when REZ_TYPE_FK = 12 then 'apex-cal-lime'
    end as CSS_REZ   /*Varchar2 that paints my calendar entries to a certain color */
from
    REZERVACIJE
where 
    (nvl(:REZ_TYPE_OBJ,'0') = '0' or REZ_TYPE_FK = :REZ_TTYPE_OBJ)  /* This is for a LOV selection where i can filter what RESERVATION TYPE i want to see*/
order by
    START_REZ
```

So I just want to show in the title the name of the `RESERVATION TYPE` from the other table. I know this is such a rookie question and is probably very simple but please have patience because I just started.

Comment: Your second `case` statement can be rewritten so instead of `case when column = value then ... when column = value then ...` to `case column when value then ... when value then ...`

Comment: `from REZERVACIJE R inner join REZERVACIJE_TYPE RT on R.REZ_TYPE_FK = RT.ID_REZTYPE`. and in `SELECT` - `RT.ReservationTypeName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following assumptions:

1. "The other table" is named `RESERVATION_TYPES` with primary key `RESERVATION_TYPE_ID` and the column that needs to be displayed is `RESERVATION_TYPE_NAME`
2. The column `REZERVACIJE.REZ_TYPE_FK` always has a value.

The select would be:

```
select 
    R.ID_REZ, /*ID of the reservation, number goes up by 1 on every insert automatically generated*/
    R.START_REZ, /*DATE OF THE START OF THE RESERVATION*/
    R.END_REZ, /*DATE OF THE END OF THE RESERVATION*/
    R.DETAILS_REZ, /*VARCHAR2 - comments on the reservation*/
    case 
        when R.DETAILS_REZ is not null 
        then R.title || '[' || R.QUANTITY_REZ || 'x ' || T.RESERVATION_TYPE_NAME
             || ' hours on ' || R.NUMBER_OF_HOURS || ' - ' || R.DETAILS_REZ || ' ]'
    end as title,
    R.QUANTITY_REZ, /* NUMBER Quantity of things on the reservation */
    R.NUMBER_OF_HOURS, /*NUMBER of hours of the reservation calculated automatically*/
    case
        when R.REZ_TYPE_FK = 8
        then  'apex-cal-red' /*THIS FK is a number 
Identity: always, in increments of 1 that connects to another table that has a name price etc and is saved in my RESERVATION table as a foreign key and I don't want to display it as a number but as a name of the RESERVATION TYPE*/
        when R.REZ_TYPE_FK = 9 then  'apex-cal-orange'
        when R.REZ_TYPE_FK = 10  then  'apex-cal-blue'
        when R.REZ_TYPE_FK = 11 then 'apex-cal-green'
        when R.REZ_TYPE_FK = 12 then 'apex-cal-lime'
    end as R.CSS_REZ   /*Varchar2 that paints my calendar entries to a certain color */
from
    REZERVACIJE R
    JOIN RESERVATION_TYPES T ON R.REZ_TYPE_FK = T.RESERVATION_TYPE_ID
where 
    (nvl(:REZ_TYPE_OBJ,'0') = '0' or R.REZ_TYPE_FK = :REZ_TTYPE_OBJ)  /* This is for a LOV selection where i can filter what RESERVATION TYPE i want to see*/
order by
    R.START_REZ
```

Replace the values in assumption (1) with the actual table/column names. If assumption (2) is incorrect you will not get a row for records that have a NULL value for `R.REZ_TYPE_FK`. Change `JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if you want all the records.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Managed to do it. The assumption was perfect!
Maybe another newbie question but why does everyone place the "nickname" R for the table Reservation and T for reservation types? I tried and it works perfectly without it as well?  Is that just so I have "cleaner" code and can find what I need more easily? Or does it have a more technical reason ?

Comment: The "nickname" is the alias. If you select from multiple tables that are joined it is advised to prefix the column names with the table they belong to - or - a lot less typing, with the table alias. I picked "r" for reservations and "t" for types but any value goes. "res" or "x" or "table1" would all work too. If the columns do not have same names this is technically not necessary but I find it makes the query a lot easier to read with aliases that have a bit of a meaning.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple use case for JOIN

```
select
    r.*,
    rt.rez_type_name
from
    reservation r
    join
    reservation_type rt on rt.res_type_id = r.res_type_id
```

Comment: right idea, bad execution

Comment: bad execution how?

Comment: 1. OP is raw. Nice to add `INNER` to join. 2. OP has exact column name `RT.REZ_TYPE_FK`. Hopefully, OP will figure out...

Comment: well we don't actually know the name of the column in the reference table, so I figured a simple example would suffice

Comment: I was a bit confused about this at first but I understood it quickly enough! Thank you for the nice and compact answer!